# override include php if logged in

Tags: php

I'm working on a login system. I want when I login at index.php, the include from that page change to another. So in my case the fully header change and the login button disappear.

So I want to change `<?php include('header.php'); ?>`
 
to

```
<?php include('header2.php'); ?>
```

if logged in

The login:

```
<div id="loginContainer">
            <a href="#" id="loginButton"><span>Login</span><em></em></a>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div id="loginBox">                
                <form id="loginForm" action="login.php" autocomplete="on" method="post">
                    <fieldset id="body">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                           <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" placeholder="myusername"/>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /> 
                        <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />Remember me</label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <span><a href="#">Forgot your password?</a></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div></
```

Part of login.php

```
if($res = $mysqli->query($q))
{
    if($res->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
        //header("Location:welcome.php");
        include('header4.php');
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo'<script>alert("INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD");</script>';
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear.

Comment: Change `$fileName` as you will and use `<?php include($fileName); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if a session is set, and then include the right file. Something like this.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userName']) && !empty($_SESSION['userName'])) {
    // If the user is logged in, include this file
    include "header2.php";
} else {
    // Else, we're not logged in, include this file
    include "header.php";
}
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to check also if $_SESSION['userName'] is not empty - since if can be set but empty (in case the user logged out).

Comment: Depends on the structure in his login, but you're absolutely right - I'll edit it in. Thanks.

Comment: If you check for !empty you won't need the isset part.